# PCMCIA NIC with 2 ports

Tags: laptop, nic

I have a laptop which I want to turn into a PFSense router. To do this I need a minimum of two network ports, which is fine, because I have one built in port and I can purchase a PCMCIA NIC with one port as well.  However, I want to I have two WAN ports and one LAN port so I can have failover internet access.

Have you ever seen a PCMCIA card with 2 Ethernet ports built in?  I can only find single NIC PCMCIA cards...

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a small Atom "book pc" box for a firewall. I use a USB nic for the Internet interface. No issue and the USB nic is faster then my DSL so it all works well.

Comment: That's what I am planning to do as well...

Answer (score 1):

I dont know of any dual port pcmcia cards, but you could use a single port card and a usb ethernet adapter, assuming your OS supports one.